# Why is there extra space in the div element when I use a percentage value as the width?

Tags: html

In this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/JPili/pen/rrpEWr), why is there no space when "#spatula"'s width is a pixel value:

```
#spatula { width: 50px; }
```

but as soon as it's a percentage value:

```
#spatula { width: 10%; }
```

there's extra space on the right?

Comment: Because 10% of 300px are 30px, and not 50px …?

Comment: Those are just examples. Come on now. No matter what percentage is used, there's always random extra space on the right. No matter what pixel value is used, the extra space is never there. You'll see if you actually click the CodePen.

Comment: Yes, “come on now” - and go read [ask] and [mcve], please. It is very unclear what you want to _achieve_ here, so give us a _proper_ explanation of that first of all.

Comment: Actually when you use 16,6% (what is 50px for 300px in %) you don't have the extra space.

Comment: It's a question. I wanna know why there's extra space whenever a percentage is used but no extra space whenever a pixel value is used for the #spatula's width. I honestly think you're being uptight for no good reason, Cbroe.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on the size of the container if you operate with percentages, they will be calculated in relation to the size of its parent, the container. If in revenche you display in pixel, they will be displayed relative to the pixels of the screen. The pixels do not change according to the size of the screen or their parent containers. Pixels are a fixed and non-variant measure.